# Why 2 threads incrementing one variable can result in different outputs

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

I just started learning concurrent programming, and even though I have a vague idea about this, why can two threads incrementing one variable result in different outputs?

Let's say the variable `i` is global, and there are two threads trying to do

```
i = i + 1;
```

Why can the output be either 1 or 2?
And assuming the main thread doesn't quit, because I know that it is possible that sometimes the main thread quits before one of the threads is able to do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Because addition operation is [not atomic](http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability):

> In concurrent programming, an operation (or set of operations) is
> atomic if it appears to the rest of the system to occur instantaneously.
>
> **Atomicity is a guarantee of isolation from concurrent processes.**

Keeping that in mind, consider the following (simplified) illustration. The operation `i = i + 1` is made up of three atomic operations:

- read the current value of `i` from the memory
- add 1 to the value that was read
- write `i` back to memory

When two threads try to perform `i = i + 1`, they may both get the same current value of `i`, and then set it to `i + 1`, making it appear that only `1` was incremented. Consider the following 2 possible scenarios:

#### Scenario 1

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 1;

Thread 1: Reads i       // Reads 0
Thread 1 : i = i + 1    // Adds 1 to i
Thread 1: Write i = 1   // Makes i == 1
Thread 2: Reads i;      // Reads 1
Thread 2: i = i + 1     // Adds 1 to i, making i == 2
Thread 2: Write i = 2   // Makes i == 2

// Finally, i becomes 2
```

In the above scenario, everything works as expected. But what happens when Thread 2 reads before Thread 1 writes the value of `i`?

#### Scenario 2

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 1;

Thread 1: Reads i       // Reads 0
Thread 1 : i = i + 1    // Adds 1 to i
Thread 2: Reads i;      // Reads 0 - NOT 1 because it's not written to memory yet
Thread 1: Write i = 1   // Makes i == 1
Thread 2: i = i + 1     // Adds 1 to i, making i == 1 (Remember, thread 2 had read 0)
Thread 2: Write i = 1   // Makes i == 1

// i is finally 1, instead of 2
```

Comment: This is an over-simplification. Modern compilers break programs with race conditions in incomprehensible ways. Saying it is undefined behavior would be a better answer than guessing how the undefined behavior manifests.

Comment: The answer is oversimplified and generally incorrect. For instance, reading and writing into memory are atomic only on certain platforms under certain conditions, and generally, even read and write are not atomic by default.